# How do you pronounce 'Tej'?

Tags: names, lois-mcmaster-bujold, vorkosigan-saga, pronunciation

[Ivan's book](http://www.baenebooks.com/chapters/9781451638455/9781451638455.htm?blurb) is finally here, and there's a new character named *Akuti Tejaswini Jyoti ghem Estif Arqua*, or *Tej* for short. I don't think I even want to *attempt* that mouthful of a full name, but I need a mental-voice pronunciation for *Tej*, and I can't seem to come up with a satisfactory one.

- My main problem is that *tej* is the Hungarian word for milk, pronounced /tey/ with *e* as in *bet* and *y* as in *yellow*. So while this is the pronunciation I keep trying to use, it just Doesn't Work<sup>TM</sup> for the character in question. (Really. She is nothing like milk.)
- There's an Indian name *Tej* (possibly short for *Tejas*) which is pronounced /tage/ (rhymes with *page*) - but it's a masculine name, not a feminine one.
- *Tejaswini* itself is also Indian, and feminine, but the first syllable is pronounced with *e* as in *bet*, and tedge-rhymes-with-edge just doesn't sound good on its own.

Is there any Word of God on this subject? Failing that, does anyone have the audiobook?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The author says the name a few times in [this reading](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=YtcZWPz5W-s&feature=youtu.be&t=29s). On the first occasion it almost rhymes with "edge" (/*'tedʒ*/). On the second occasion it's closer to /*'teʒ*/

---

I've also isolated a couple of examples from the audiobook

[Here](http://vocaroo.com/i/s1Cqp1IRTlBE) and [here](http://vocaroo.com/i/s1QsI8LdT0DM)

Answer (score 6):

OK, Word of God has been acquired (thank you, Chester County Book Company [and Baen, of course]): Lois pronounces "Tej" as /tehzh/, with /eh/ as in *bet* and /zh/ like the *s* in *measure*.

Now, granted, this is from the same person who pronounces "Enrique" as /en-ree-kee/, so we're not talking authentic native pronunciation or anything. But it's good enough for my mental voice.

Comment: It may help to elaborate on what the source of the info is.

Comment: @DVK: uh, hello, "Word of God"? Lois McMaster Bujold was signing books at a local bookstore, and I asked her point-blank how to pronounce Ivan's lady's name.

Comment: @Martha I think the issue is more, we don't have proof you didn't just make it up...

Comment: @Izkata Then go to a book signing!

Comment: Given that Tej's father picked her names from books, it makes sense that he wouldn't know how to pronounce them in a historically authentic way.

Answer (score 4):

Tej means 'brightness' or 'illumination'. It is generally used to describe the aura or illumination that surrounds enlightened, intellectual beings. Tejas means the one who has Tej and is a male name. Tejaswini is a female name with the same meaning as that of Tejas.

Help with pronunciation - 
You're right. Tej rhymes with page but the pronunciation of T is not a 'hard' one as it is in case of 'Tiger'. The pronunciation of Tej's T doesnt come deeply from the throat, as it would in case of tiger..

PS: I'm an Indian.

Comment: I'm confused: how on earth would you go about pronouncing a /t/ "deeply from the throat"? Seems anatomically impossible, like you'd have to swallow your tongue first. That aside: do Indians use *Tej* as a short form of *Tejaswini*? If yes, is it pronounced the same way as the masculine name? How hard is the 'g' - is it sorta-soft like in *jam* or more like the 'dg' in *edge*? And beyond all that, do we know how Bujold intended the name to be pronounced? I mean, we're talking 30th century Barrayar, not 21st century India.

Comment: Yes. 'Tej' would be an acceptable short form of Tejaswini. The 'g' would be soft like in jam. The 't' would sound something like 'th' in path or sith.